# Heavy I/O with events firing much faster than they can be handled, causing problematic backlog

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, entity-framework, service-broker

In a nutshell, my project is receiving data faster than it can process and then write it to a database (EF6 to SQL Server 2016), and I'm not sure what the best-practice approach is (ditch EF? Offload to database via Service Broker?  Something else?)  Write events are not being handled fast enough, so they result in cascading event logjams and fatal memory crashes.

The write events are (I want them to be) low-priority, and I'm using async tasks for them.  The write events involve a lot of data and a lot of relationships, and EF is just not handling them efficiently (I'm using AddRange, but EF is just sending everything in many single inserts, which I've read is its regular behavior).

I've tried paring back the relationships, and I've moved more processing over to the database, and I've tried using a batched "Delayed"Queue (an observable queue implementation that triggers an "empty me" event when a threshold is met), so that the inbound write events can be handled very quickly (just dump the request in the queue and move on), but this didn't get me anywhere (not surprising, I suppose, since I've basically added a message queue on top of the built-in message queue?).

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems to me that EF is not the right tool for something as write-heavy and relationship-heavy as what I have (I know there are bulk-write extensions...).  So, in an effort to resolve this sensibly, would it make sense to bypass EF and do my own bulk-write queries, or is this an appropriate use for Service Broker?  With Service Broker, I could just send a dataset in one sproc, which just adds the dataset to the queue, frees the frontend to move on, and the database can handle and build the relationships whenever.  Are these solutions sensible or best practice, or am I barking up the wrong tree (or putting lipstick-on-a-pig maybe)?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you getting a continuous constant stream of data, or bursts? In case of bursts, you may put a queue in between. External broker like RabbitMQ, Kafka or even Redis. The writer will catch-up after a burst. If you have a consistent stream which has larger throughput than your DB write layer can handle - optimize write SQL, move to plain, batch SQL, remove some indexes or triggers in DB. In the end you may need to look at write-fast noSQL data store.

Comment: @PiotrGwiazda It's a constant stream with occasional sustained bursts.  I'll look into those external brokers, thanks!  I agree that I need to focus on the datalayer and roll my own SQL.  In the end, at the intake stage of the application, it doesn't care about the relationships (and that is what I think is bogging EF down), so if that is where my costs are, then it makes sense to assign those tasks to the database.

Answer (score 1):

> Please correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems to me that EF is not the
>   right tool for something as write-heavy and relationship-heavy as what
>   I have

You are right.

By default like you said, Entity Framework perform one database round-trip for every record to save which is **INSANELY** slow.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of [Entity Framework Extensions](http://entityframework-extensions.net/)

*(The library is not free)*

This library allows you to improve Entity Framework Performance.

I'm not sure if our library can help you but it worth a try if you save multiple entities at once.

By example, the BulkSaveChanges is exactly like SaveChanges but way faster by dramatically reducing the database round-trip required.

- Bulk SaveChanges
- Bulk Insert
- Bulk Delete
- Bulk Update
- Bulk Merge

Example

```
// Easy to use
context.BulkSaveChanges();

// Easy to customize
context.BulkSaveChanges(bulk => bulk.BatchSize = 100);

// Perform Bulk Operations
context.BulkDelete(endItems);
context.BulkInsert(endItems);
context.BulkUpdate(endItems);

// Customize Primary Key
context.BulkMerge(endItems, operation => {
   operation.ColumnPrimaryKeyExpression = 
        endItem => endItem.Code;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond!  If I stick with EF, I'll dig further into your extensions.  But I think for my use case I might benefit more by just shifting the work out of my frontend and into the datalayer, since the frontend doesn't care about the relationships at the time of receipt, so forcing EF to do all that work when the datalayer can do it alone seems wasteful.